# PL/SQL - Número incorreto de tipos de argumentos na chamada

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Estou com problema em uma função simples que criei.

```
create or replace FUNCTION dry_login (
    username IN VARCHAR2,
    password IN VARCHAR2 )
RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
    l_user varchar2(70);
    l_pwd  varchar2(70);
BEGIN
  SELECT usuario_nome, usuario_senha
    INTO l_user, l_pwd
    FROM dry_usuario
  WHERE usuario_nome = username;

IF (l_pwd = password) and (l_user = username) THEN
    RETURN TRUE;
ELSE
    RETURN FALSE;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN RETURN FALSE;
END;
```

Da o seguinte erro:

ORA-06550: linha 4, coluna 23:
PLS-00306: número incorreto de tipos de argumentos na chamada para 'DRY_LOGIN'
ORA-06550: linha 4, coluna 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Alguém me ajude a achar esse erro, por favor.
Obrigado.
Att
Oliver

Comment: Como e onde está chamando essa função?

Comment: É no APEX.
Ao fazer o login eu coloquei pra executar essa function, e no login eu informo usuario e senha

Comment: O erro não está na função e sim na chamada da função, se puder incluir a cópia da chamada a função, com as variáveis de ambiente indicadas no APEX fica mais fácil para identificar o possível erro.

Comment: Quais argumentos passa na chamada da função?

Answer (score 2):

Eu fucei no APEX e vi que já esta definido o nome do parâmetro na chamada do método.
Fica a dica caso alguém precisar, fiz a seguinte alteração.

```
create or replace FUNCTION dry_login (
    p_username IN VARCHAR2,
    p_password IN VARCHAR2 )
```

Obrigado pela atenção e ajuda de todos.